# 403 Authentication Credentials not provided NextJS Django

Tags: django, typescript, next.js, session-cookies

FRONTEND:

```
 useEffect(() => {
      async function fetchProfile() {
        try {
          const response = await fetch("/api/user_profile",
          {
           headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            credentials: 'include'
          });
           const data = await response.json();
           setUserProfile(data);
          
      } catch(err){
          console.error("Error fetching profile data", err);
      }

    }

      fetchProfile();
       
    },[]);

  useEffect(() => {
        // Log the user profile state
        console.log(userProfile);
    }, [userProfile]);
```

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'


export async function GET(request: Request) {
  const cookieStore = cookies(request);
  const sessionID = cookieStore.get('sessionid')?.value;
  const csrfToken = cookieStore.get('csrftoken')?.value;

  const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/profile/', {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Cookie': `sessionid=${sessionID}; csrftoken=${csrfToken}`,
    },
  });

  const response_data = await response.json();
  return Response.json({ response_data });
}
```

BACKEND:

```
class UserProfileView(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_profile, _ = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user = request.user)
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(user_profile, data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()

            return Response(serializer.data)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=request.user)
        serializer = UserProfileSerializer(user_profile)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class LoginView(views.APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')

        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)

        if user is None:
            return Response({'error': 'Invalid Credentials'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

        login(request, user)
        return Response({'message': 'User logged in successfully'})
```

The problem is I cannot access my user profile endpoint even with passing the details. I have a rough idea that it may be that the cookies are not being passed properly server-side. I am using session-based authentication. On login I receive a CSRF token as well as a sessionid. I observed that in the dev tools that the cookies were being set as normal

1. I successfully managed to log in a user and redirected to the dashboard using NextJS router.
2. Whenever I go on the profile I want to fetch the user profile data client side. From looking at the Next docs, its good practice to use the route handler.
3. From there I saw that it still didnt authorize me, so searching I found that, you can't access the browser API serverside
4. Then I explored further and found that you can manually add cookies to the headers, and tried to implement this, but still received the same error.
5. I did observe that it was 403 error meaning it is a valid request but the auth system will not authorize me
6. Then I tried it on Postman, which worked meaning it after going through the whole register, login, fetchProfile process one by one.